# 言葉で話したことがリアルタイムで文字として、印刷されるシステムを作りたい

Tags: python

今までプログラミングの経験はなく、今回、pythonを導入しました。使用して１か月も経っていない全くの初心者です。

実行環境は Windows 10, Python 3.9.7 です。プリンターとして、を使用しています。このプリンターは試してみたところ、専用のアプリなどを入れていなくても、wordなどで書いた文字が印刷できるのは確認しました。

やりたいことは、音声を文字にして紙に印刷するということです。
今、わかっている範囲での問題は、音声入力の終了の方法と、入ってきた文章を印刷する方法、そしてこれらの動作を繰り返して、行う方法です。

可能であれば、これらの動作を一環として行えるようにしたいと思っています。
何かいい方法は、ないでしょうか。ご教授お願いします。

Comment: 音声入力の終了の方法が問題となっているということは、既に何かしらの音声入力の方法を試していらっしゃるようです。回答の助けになるので、どんな風にやってらっしゃるのかも質問文を [edit] して書いていただけないでしょうか。

Comment: 文章を印刷したいということですが、ラベルプリンターのようなものを使って順次印刷していきたいのか、それとも一通り喋り終わってから完成品を A4 用紙などに印刷したいのか、などで事情が変わってきそうです。より詳細な情報を質問文に追記していただけないでしょうか。

Comment: 当サイトは日本語でのやり取りを前提にしているので、英語の併記は不要です。 / プリンターの情報が抜け落ちているように見えますが、必要に応じて編集での追記をお願いします。

Comment: こちら参考になると思いますが、ご覧になっているでしょうか？https://qiita.com/teahat/items/86b68e03056e914c80f8

Comment: ご教授ありがとうございます。　プリンターは、Peripage　mini  printerのA６203dpiです。ロール状の感熱紙でラベル状に印刷されていきます。　音声入力に関してはこちらのサイトを参考にながら進めている段階でまだ完成していません。https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/streaming-recognize?hl=ja　　　　　　終了方法が問題というのは、プログラムに詳しい同級生に話を聞いたところ出てきた問題です。

Comment: ありがとうございます。qiita.com/teahat/items/86b68e03056e914c80f8 のサイト確認しました。参考になりそうなので取り入れてみたいと思います。